# numpy sin and cos don't return exactly zero for reference angles that have zero values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a problem with numpy not returning zero when calculating cos(pi/2).

On my TI calculator this returns exactly zero, however numpy is returning an extremely small number instead.

Is there a way to fix this problem for sin/cos functions in numpy, or perhaps switch to sympy for these calculations so that it only return zero for well known reference angles that are suppose to return zero?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.cos(numpy.pi/2.0)
6.123233995736766e-17
```

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: One solution is to switch to sympy when calculating sin's and cos's, when to switch back to numpy using sp.N(...) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> value = sp.N(sp.cos(sp.pi/2))
0
```

Comment: if this question was asked before, then where's the link? and also your link to floating point doesn't answer the question.

Comment: A numeric `pi` is not exact.  It's an approximation.  So any function using it will also be an approximation.